# How to find the roots of polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the polynomial $x^{p-1} - 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. What are its roots / how does it factor?

Does this factorization tell you anything about $(p-1)!$ modulo $p$?

I'm really stuck on this problem. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: The way most number theory courses are organized, you already know a relevant theorem.

Answer (score 6):

This is equivalent to showing that the roots of $x^p - x$ are exactly $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be roots of this. Then $a^p \equiv a$ and $b^p \equiv b$ mod $p$.

Consider $(a + b)^p$. If you write out the binomial expansion, you get
$$(a + b)^p \equiv a^p + \binom{p}{1} a^{p-1} b + \cdots + \binom{p}{p - 1} a b^{p-1} + b^p$$ But $\binom{p}{k}$ is divisible by $p$ when $k \ne 0, p$. So $(a + b)^p \equiv a^p + b^p \equiv a + b$, and so $a + b$ is also a root.

Since $1$ is obviously a root, and all elements can be made by repeated $1$s, all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are roots of $x^p - x$. When we divide by $x$, we have to toss out $0$ as a root, so the roots are exactly $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^\times$.

As for the other part, you now know $x^{p-1} - 1$ factors as $(x - 1)(x - 2)\cdots(x - (p-1))$. You can now swap $k$ with $p - k$ to get $(x + 1)(x + 2)\cdots(x + (p-1))$. So the constant term is $(p-1)!$, and so it must be $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried anything yet?

If not, put "try simple examples" into your list of things that you try before you declare yourself unable to do anything. You should be able to solve the $p=2, 3, 5$ cases all by hand (and possibly more), and from that, hopefully gain information about the general problem.

Some other things to do before you declare yourself stuck are:

- Guessing things. You're looking for roots, so you could always just try *guessing* at them. Turns out that you'll probably find one, which may or may not help.
- Transform the problem. There is a qualitatively different way to state the problem "What are the roots of $x^{p-1} - 1$". It turns out that this different statement directly relates to the structure of finite fields, and may suggest a way to proceed. There might be other transformations that might make the problem more clear (e.g. there's a related polynomial you might be familiar with).
- Solve a related problem. Is there *any* field in which you can find the roots of $x^{p-1} - 1$? Often, solving an algebraic problem in the complex numbers will suggest things that might be true of the corresponding problem in other fields.