# factoring polynomials in $\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Any ideas as in how to Factor $x^{10}-1$ into linear factors in the integers modulo $11$, $\Bbb Z_{11}=\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z$?

I've been trying but can't come up with an answer.

Comment: Do you know anything about Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Not really. I've heard of it but not quite sure about it

Comment: Well, then compute $1^{10}$, $2^{10}$, $3^{10}$ and so on mod $11$. See what you come up with.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question four days ago? I even remember giving you an [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866421/how-to-find-the-roots-of-polynomials-in-bbb-z-p/). And speaking of answers, you should [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the ones that you find most helpful (right now, it looks like you've accepted answers on 0/13 questions).

Answer (score 2):

All nonzero elements of $\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z$ are 10th roots of 1, so it's just

$$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\ldots (x-10)$$